# Is SCV pathing random or deterministic while building?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to determine or control where a SCV moves during construction?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63220/is-it-possible-to-determine-or-control-where-a-scv-moves-during-construction)

In Starcraft 2, SCVs (the basic Terran building and gathering unit) move around and through the buildings that they are constructing as the building process takes place.  Is this movement deterministic or is it pseudorandom?

Note that I don't mean to get into a philosophical discussion about determinism or something of that nature.  I understand that pseudorandom number generators are, technically speaking, deterministic.  Rather, I'm curious as to whether the pathing is something that can be predicted and planned for during a game or if it is "random".

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I'm wondering why an SCV's pathing during building construction is of importance to you?

Comment: It is very useful information for melee attackers. When a Terran is trying to wall in, if one knows the SCV will be available on all four sides, he can time an attack to kill the SCV

Comment: In sc2, *any* predictable behavior can be used strategically.